# format of ByteArray returned from C is invalid

Tags: c, actionscript-3, apache-flex, alchemy

following is code snippet:

AS side:(img is reference to an `<Image>` instance)

```
        bitmapData = Bitmap(img.content).bitmapData;
        var pixels:ByteArray = bitmapData.getPixels(bitmapData.rect);
        pixels.position = 0;
        var output:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        img_width = bitmapData.width;
        img_height = bitmapData.height;
        ////invoke C code by alchemy
        lomoEncoder.encode(pixels, output, img_width, img_height);
        var newImage:Image = new Image();
        //can't show the image
        newImage.source = output;
```

C code:

```
AS3_Val dest;
AS3_Val source;
unsigned char* pixels = (unsigned char *)malloc(Size);
AS3_ByteArray_readBytes(pixels, source, Size);
pixels = darkCornerLomoEffect((unsigned char*)pixels, image_width, image_height);
AS3_ByteArray_writeBytes(dest, (char*) pixels, length);
```

In the AS side, when get the `dest` from C, loader.load(dest) throw an error:Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2124.
So How to deal with the byteArray format, so AS side can reorganize and use it as `Image` source property?

Comment: I think we need to see the AS3 that calls the Alchemy C code.  Are you passing in a ByteArray for dest?  Also, where is the C code that unmarshals the arguments?

Comment: @paleozogt:I have update the code snippet. Does C have any rules for unmarshal byteArray, so AS can use the value return from C?thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you have a bytearray and you want to load the image source you can do the following:

```
var b:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var f:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 100);
f.setPixels(new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100), b);
```

please can you provide a snippet of your AS3 code?

Comment: :I have update the code snippet. Does C have any rules for unmarshal byteArray, so AS can use the value return from C? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem is [byte-ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315417/convert-little-endian-bytearray-to-big-endian-in-as3).  You need to flip your bytes after reading from the input ByteArray.  For the output ByteArray you either need to flip them again, or set its `endian` property to `Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN`.